# Like box and button not displaying in all browsers

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a Facebook Like Button and Box installed on a website and it is only working in Safari, not any of the other browsers. I used the HTML5 coding from Facebook for both. The website is http://www.genesisobgyn.org. The like button should be above the Google+ button and the box should be next to the News section.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shows in Chrome. FF has the error `[13:28:00.954] "Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id."`

Comment: So what does that mean?

Comment: It means that in the url that instantiates the like button (are you using xfbml or js?) you're app id is either invalid, or your app doesn't have the domain included in it's site url.